# Text::CSV parsing CSV having quoted string under string like 1,"foo "bar" baz",42

Tags: csv, perl

I am looking at the documentation (https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#allow_loose_quotes)and implementing same way. However, not able to parse the string of the CSV even after turning on the allow_loose_quotes.

CSV text:
1,"foo "bar" baz",42

Parsing it like:

```
use Text::CSV

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    escape_char => '\\',
    quote_char => "\"",
    allow_loose_quotes => 1,
    sep_char => ',',
    });
```

```
while (my $line = <FH>) 
{
  chomp $line;
    
  # Parsing the line
  if ($csv->parse($line)) 
  {
      # Extracting elements
      my @words = $csv->fields();
      $worksheet->write_row($x, $y, \@words);
  } 
  else
  {
      # Warning to be displayed
      warn "Line could not be parsed: $line\n";
  }
  $x++;
}
```

Please, suggest how i can parse CSV having this kind of values.

I tried to parse as mentioned in documentation

Comment: With specified by you _csv options_ your input data should be `1,"foo \"bar\" baz",42`, perhaps it is a source of your problem.

Comment: The example provided in `Text::CSV`'s documentation works. And your code also works when I run it. So, there must be something else going on. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Dada well, it works when you fix or fill in all the missing stuff :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into my Dada, Polar Bear, Brian

Answer (score 1):

The [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) (and [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS)) docs note that you can parse a line with a field like `"a "b" c"` if you set `allow_loose_quotes` and ensure that the escape character is not the same as the quote character. Both of those are `"` by default. Note that the "escape" is a CSV feature, not a Perl string feature.

You are using `parse`, which is fine if you have a complete record in the string. However, as you read from a file, a quoted field may spread over two lines. Consider a field like `"a\nb\nc\n"` Use `getline` instead because that knows how to grab another line if it needs it to complete the record.

Here's something that works:

```
use v5.10;

use Text::CSV_XS;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
    allow_loose_quotes => 1,
    quote_char         => q("),
    escape_char        => undef,
    });

say "Quote char is ", $csv->quote_char;
say "Escape char is ", $csv->escape_char;

while( my $row = $csv->getline(*DATA) ) {
    say Dumper($row)
    }

__DATA__
1,2,3
1,"foo "bar" baz",42
"a","b","c,d"
```

This gives the output for each row:

```
Quote char is "
Escape char is
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          '2',
          '3'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          'foo "bar" baz',
          '42'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'b',
          'c,d'
        ];
```

And, for what's it worth, it's often useful to look at a module's test suite to see how it used a feature.

Answer (score -1):

After looking Dada's comment that same code is working for him. It clicked to me that I should upgrade to latest Text::CSV module and after upgrade, bingo it now worked for me as well.

Answer (score -4):

The input file is not in correct format to be parsed without an error.

Please see following code sample and inspect generated *CSV* file for it's content.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;

my(@rows,$restored_rows);
my $fname = 'new.csv';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    escape_char => '\\',
    quote_char => "\"",
    allow_loose_quotes => 1,
    sep_char => ',',
    });

@rows = (
        [1,'some "text" line 1', 42],
        [2,'some "text" line 2', 43],
        [3,'some "text" line 3', 44],
        [4,'some "text" line 4', 45]
    );

csv_save($fname,\@rows);
$restored_rows = csv_read($fname);

say Dumper($restored_rows);

exit 0;

sub csv_save {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $data  = shift;
    
    open my $fh, '>:encoding(utf8)', $fname
        or die "$fname: $!";
        
    $csv->say ($fh, $_) for $data->@*;

    close $fh
        or die "$fname: $!";
}

sub csv_read {
    my $fname = shift;
    my $data;
    
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $fname
        or die "$fname: $!";
    
    while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
        push $data->@*, $row;
    }

    close $fh;
    
    return $data;
}
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1',
            'some "text" line 1',
            '42'
          ],
          [
            '2',
            'some "text" line 2',
            '43'
          ],
          [
            '3',
            'some "text" line 3',
            '44'
          ],
          [
            '4',
            'some "text" line 4',
            '45'
          ]
        ];
```

File **new.csv** content

```
1,"some \"text\" line 1",42
2,"some \"text\" line 2",43
3,"some \"text\" line 3",44
4,"some \"text\" line 4",45
```

Comment: No. `Text::CSV` is capable of parsing this kind of input without requiring escaping the inner double quotes.